# Set RecyclerView child width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have the RecycleView that scrolls horizontally (with LinearLayoutManager). I want to set child's width as the width of the screen in portrait orientation. And set child's width as the half width of the screen in landscape orientation. How can I do this?

Comment: how do you scroll horizontally o.O

Comment: Because he is using RecyclerView and he could do whatever he wants with it :)

Comment: Have you tried getting screen sizes with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels] and setting sizes for child in measureChild / measureChildren / onLayout? Provide some code so we can see at leas something